# Glyphicon and Select in twitter bootstrap nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am struggling with this for almost an hour.

I want to have glyphicon and select in twitter bootstrap nav bar.
But because I am styling glyphicon so that it will look bigger (which is important for me)

```
{
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
```

my select positioned lower than it should (it is not in the center). Also if I resize the window, both icon and select are going down, nonetheless there is plenty of room. If I remove one element (either select or icon), another one looks ok. I tried to use `line-height`, `margin`, `padding` to solve the problem, but without any luck.

Can any CSS guru tell me how should I make it look nice? Please [find my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/8u3vy/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
.navbar-default select
{
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

The resizing "problem" is happening due to the responsiveness features of Bootstrap. [You can disable it.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)